# So, what's happening to my reputation? How do I report something fishy?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

https://stackoverflow.com/users/572?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top - Between 2009/09/27 and 2009/09/28...

That's unusual for me...to have 6 downvotes in less than 20 minutes. Now, I normally don't care about my rep, but this is just fishy...

So, what is the procedure for such things? Wait until the automated systems kick in and do something? Post here on Meta? Flag a post that was downvoted for review by a mod and use the text field to explain it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/572?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top the search for dates Start: 2009/09/27 End: 2009/09/28

Comment: I can see a few downvotes, but nothing I'd get hugely excited about...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If, **after 36 hours** (this is to ensure the daily voting anomaly scripts have run) you still have issues with your rep, email us via the address at the bottom of every page.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know SOP is to put your faith in the autobot and let it go. Flagging for mod attention or raising with the SO team does seem... inefficient... as you've said.

The* problem I have with relying on the bot is that it's a (necessarily) opaque mechanism, and life goes on so it's almost impossible for me to tell if or when it's working, or those downvotes remain standing.

But then again, rep is just a number right?

* *Ok, apart from the problem with that guy who keeps downvoting me but apparently not in a systemic enough way for a non-human to notice.*

Comment: Awesome - having said this I just caught two downvotes in 2 minutes. Somebody testing my resolve?

Answer (score 3):

the moderators' oath: "we pledge our lives, our reputations, and our sacred free time..."

Answer (score 1):

If you flag one of the posts, and use the text to explain what you've seen to the moderators, one of them can likely take a look for you.

Comment: Yes, but is that standard procedure? What warrants that? I mean, mods have lives too.

Comment: @Thomas, I wouldn't make a habit of doing this, but if this is a rare occurrence as you suggest, I don't see a problem with your flagging and letting them look into it a little bit. It could just be a coincidence, but on the surface seems fishy.

Comment: Additionally, if you were to start flagging too frequently about receiving downvotes, I would hope and expect that the SO team, would contact you about the issue and let you know that you need to scale it back.

Comment: I would hope so too. I think I'll sit back and let the automated system handle this one - there was no significant impact. But I'm sure other users have asked this.

Comment: @Thomas. The moderators sacrificed their lives for the good of the SOFU collective.You should do the same.