# Why serial downvoters are allowed in the community?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, comments, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [So, what's happening to my reputation? How do I report something fishy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/so-whats-happening-to-my-reputation-how-do-i-report-something-fishy)

Allowing downvoting a question or answer is not a bad idea in itself, even without leaving any comment/reason why the downvoter downvoted, though posting a comment usually helps the poster to correct himself.

Usually, I don't want to know *who* downvoted me, though sometimes I want to know *why* I'm downvoted!

In this topic, I particularly want to know : Why **a serial downvoter** is allowed to downvote or even allowed in the community? Can't the system detect that a particular person is downvoting posts one after another without giving a serious thought? Like, timestamp can help to detect this?

For example, I just saw that **someone downvoted my 17 questions within less than 4 minutes? Is this behaviour allowed? Why is this behavior allowed? Is there any rationale for that?**  I'm sure he didn't read my questions. How can a person read 17 questions within 4 mins?

Here the screenshot of my recent downvotes:

[image]

---

EDIT:

I suspect [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418729/acme). His [recent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418729/acme?tab=reputation&repview=time) shows this:

[image]

How come his downvoted rep shows `-23`? I suspect him because [I was replying to his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362445/pointing-to-static-class-member), when I was being downvoted!!! I wonder why would he downvote me!! His [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418729/acme) shows he downvoted 27 times, and upvoted only 14 times. Something very fishy with this guy!

Also, I re-counted that I got 19 (not 17) consecutive downvotes.

Comment: Lots of good discussions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial-downvotes

Comment: He can downvote you 17 times, but his vote won't stay since there are detection mechanism that detect vote fraud.

Comment: Given that it was 17 questions in less than 4 minutes - if it was a single down-voter it **will** get detected. I've had serial up-votes removed (yes it does happen) where I got fewer up-votes than that.

Answer (score 7):

That kind of behaviour is identified and the votes are removed when voting fraud is detected.

More info [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) and [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/).

Answer (score 2):

It isn't tolerated.

In most cases, serial down voting sprees are never brought to moderator attention because the system is quite good at spotting and reversing them. I'd venture to say, at least half of the time, even the target user is unaware that anything happened.

If a moderator *does* catch someone 'red handed', it would not be unusual for the person to be put in a short cooling off 'time out' as well as a warning being issued.

There have also been cases (this is rare but it has happened)

- User B finds an answer by user A, disagrees, down votes
- User B looks at some of user A's other posts, and finds quite a bit more to *technically* disagree with. Not revenge down voting per say, but it fits the same pattern.

This would also trigger automatic reversal. In short, whenever the system sees a *user* being targeted, instead of just one or two of their answers, action is taken.

This has (as others have noted) been covered before. I'm closing this, but did want to provide a brief reply.

Comment: this guy was not only serial-downvoting, he was sockpuppeting.  If you view the question, the accepted answer was merged by JA.  Not sure why the guy didn't get the smackdown.