# Account hit by huge number of downvotes

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [So, what's happening to my reputation? How do I report something fishy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/so-whats-happening-to-my-reputation-how-do-i-report-something-fishy)

If you look at [my account on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148765/chinmay-kanchi?tab=reputation&StartDate=2011-08-14), today someone has hit the whole account with a massive series of down-votes. While this has only led to the loss of 78 reputation or so (i.e, just about 1% of my total reputation), I am a bit concerned about the possibility that someone can do this. Can something like this be reversed? Isn't there an automated system that prevents such "downvote bombing"?

While I couldn't care less about the reputation itself, I'm a bit annoyed that a whole bunch of the answers that had 0 or 1 up-votes are all negatively rated now.

Comment: Yes, in fact there *is* such an automated system. It's implemented in the form of a detection script, but it only runs once per day. You'll have to wait until it does for the downvotes to be removed. Alternatively, you can flag one of your posts for moderator attention--they can investigate the voting problem and take whatever action is necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [So, what's happening to my reputation? How do I report something fishy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/so-whats-happening-to-my-reputation-how-do-i-report-something-fishy), [Serial downvotes in quick succession on all my posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts), [Serial Downvoting Victim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

Comment: @Cody: Why not post this as an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: Because I was voting to close as a duplicate once I found the rest of the links. :-)

Comment: Fair enough :) .

Answer (score 1):

There is a system that detect anomalies in voting, and that reverts those votes, whatever they are up-votes or down-votes.

The system will detect such anomalies the day after, and it will remove all the votes that match some defined criteria, which are known from Stack Exchange stuff only. The reason they are not known is to avoid somebody plays around those criteria not to be caught.