# Malicious Downvotes

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting, tactical-downvoting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing users from downvoting good answers to bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23005/preventing-users-from-downvoting-good-answers-to-bad-questions)
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

I believe a user is using malicious down voting as a tactic for getting his answer higher than the one posted before him, then when challenged he an a friend down voted to the cap on answers of mine from a while back.  I believe this is a very negative behavior on such a positive site.  Please help.

Comment: Or possibly more apt: [So, what's happening to my reputation? How do I report something fishy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/so-whats-happening-to-my-reputation-how-do-i-report-something-fishy)

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, I'm not looking for my x reputation back.  I want to know how we can prevent this kind of behavior, or at least react to it in a community appropriate way.

Answer (score 3):

If you have been serially downvoted, the downvotes will be automatically reverted by a script.

Users that resort to serial downvoting often enough will be flagged for moderator review and can face temporary suspensions if they don't improve.

You can flag the comment where you challenged the user for the behaviour for moderator attention if you feel the user is consistently downvoting competing posts. A moderator cannot see who downvotes either though, but it may be that with some careful observations the user can be called out on the behaviour anyway.

Comment: In this case, OP has got 3 downvotes over a period of 10 minutes. The script wont pick that up. Although, it most certainly does appear to be a case of serial down-voting.

Comment: Not sure that catches the tactical downvoting alleged in the question. If the user is voting down competing answers then unlikely to be the same recipient all the time.

Comment: right, this incident is not my main concern.  What is there to discourage doing it again.  I mean if I, and everyone else just lets it go thinking the algorithm will "fix it" likely after another answer is accepted, will this user ever see repercussions for this community marring behavior.

Comment: @Gent: Users that resort to such behaviour are luckily few and far between. They'll have other issues too, they'll come to moderator attention eventually and will be dealt with accordingly. Note that downvoting answers also costs the downvoter some reputation, btw.

Answer (score 3):

These downvotes [will be removed by an automagic script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857) which detects voting fraud, usually within a day (~12-24h tops). If these have not been removed within a day or so, flag one of your questions or answers which has been downvoted with an Other message for a moderator explaining exactly what you think is going on.

However, just because you believe this is going on does not mean it is. Voting is anonymous and your questions/answers may have garnered downvotes the old fashioned way.